# Track urls using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

How to track the page views and ip address of the short url this code is creating. thanks in advance.

PHP Code

```
<?php 

//include database connection details
include('db.php');

//redirect to real link if URL is set
if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    $redirect = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = '".addslashes($_GET['url'])."'"));
    $redirect = "http://".str_replace("http://","",$redirect[url_link]);
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');  
    header("Location: ".$redirect);  
}
//

//insert new url
if ($_POST['url'] && $_POST['url'] != 'http://') {

//get random string for URL and add http:// if not already there
$short = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 5);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO urls (url_link, url_short, url_ip, url_date) VALUES

    (
    '".addslashes($_POST['url'])."',
    '".$short."',
    '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
    '".time()."'
    )

");

$redirect = "?s=$short";
header('Location: '.$redirect); die;

} 

<h1> URL to shrink: </h1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input name="url" type="text" id="url" value="http://" size="75" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<!--if form was just posted-->
<?php if (!empty($_GET['s'])) { ?>
<br />
<h2>Here's the short URL: <a href="<?php echo $server_name; ?><?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $server_name; ?><?php echo $_GET['s']; ?></a></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a separate table for keeping a count of the hits and IP's your shortened URL's are getting. Create a table (let's call it "hits") containing url_id and ip_address as it's columns.

Inside your `if (!empty($_GET['url']))` condition, make an insert into the hits table with the ID of the URL it has requested and the IP address the request came from.

Answer (score -1):

> How to track the page views and ip address of the short url this code is creating.

Enable logging in your webserver and then use a log file analyzer that will give you that information (most common logfile analyzers do have the info you're looking for).